# How can I add a playlist to content type?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to add a playlist of mp3 or waves to custom content type. I installed some modules, but nothing seems to work:

- I installed audiofield that allows upload of files.
- I installed some plugins, such as wordpress player, but it isn't accessible to screen readers (flash buttons are unlabeled).
- I installed jPlayer, but there are many errors when I attempt to display content, such as undefined index.continuous, undefined index.entity etc.
- I installed able player, an accessible able player, but tracks are not visible.
- I try to install jw_player, but it doesn't install due an error index.description undefined.
- I tried to set file field as an audio file, but track are not visible.
- I tried to change theme, switched to bootstrap instead of bartik, but nothing change.

I don't know how to do. Is Drupal able to play audio files?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? What do you mean by playlist? What level of accessibility you want to achieve? Please extend your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aptly named [AudioField](https://www.drupal.org/project/audiofield) module has the functionality you're describing

> Audio Field module adds new field that allows you to upload and play audio files in HTML5 audio player or one of selected Flash players. Currently it supports 6 different Flash players

It definitely works, I've used it, and it has support for both of the formats you mentioned. Follow the installation instructions and you shouldn't have any problems.

Just to nitpick, and perhaps clear up some confusion: Drupal cannot play audio files, no - your browser can, when it is given the right HTML (or when flash is used). But Drupal just generates the HTML, it doesn't have anything to do with the audio files themselves (beyond facilitating upload/storage) or how the browser interprets them.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to give the [Media module](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) a try. Make sure you download the latest [7.x-2.0-rc3](https://www.drupal.org/project/media/releases/7.x-2.0-rc3) release. One of its features:

> Makes files fieldable, enabling the use of text fields to store
>   captions on images, taxonomy fields for audio file genres, etc.

Comment: Thanks to all, I solved. I installed html5 tools and able player. It's an audio/video player accessible to screen readers and with html5 tools works fine. Thanks again!